# Google Authenticator - Counter Based

Tags: authentication, php, google, oauth, one-time-password

I'm trying to understand How google authenticator - counter based work. I have tried googling around finding a demo or at least how this work. I understand its a one time password but not like TOTP. I am already working on TOTP but i'm terribly having issue with time sync, because i'm working on an offline PC. So the windows time - well every 2 days or so the time keep shifting two or three seconds ahead.

Anyways, I am looking for a PHP code for HOTP counter based . I have found one or two examples but they have so many missing files.

Please, I would like to find a tutorial about that in PHP language or at least a basic idea to start with. 
BTW i found this http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt  .

Answer (score 1):

[TOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) is indeed a time-based variant of [HOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226). In both cases, the sequence of possible passwords is derived from a secret key, and a "changing value". With TOTP, the "changing value" is the current time, which both ends of the protocol supposedly know (current time is public knowledge). In HOTP, the "changing value" is a counter, which is incremented after usage. Both parties (client and server) remember the last used counter value.

If the client and server become desynchronized (e.g. the client sent a password and incremented its counter, but a network issue killed the connection and the server never received it), then there is a process for resynchronization: upon receiving a password, the server compares it not with the next password (according to its counter), but with the next 100 or so passwords, thus allowing for a counter desynchronization of a 100 or so.

This mechanism is well suited to car keys, which:

- Do not have a common source of time (no clock in the key).
- Need to work with a unidirectional communication (from key to car, not the other way round).
- Have a "manual resynchronization" if they got badly out of sync (your 3 years old nephew played with the key for an entire afternoon, getting the key counter way beyond the car counter, even with the +100 offset; you can no longer open the car remotely; but when you ignite the engine, the car and the key communicate through short-range RF to reset the counters).

As for code, a simple google request on "hotp php" points to [this](https://github.com/Jakobo/hotp-php) and [that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have PHP code for you, but here is a project I used when porting this to one of my companies legacy systems because there were not direct ports I could reference.  It's in C# and you can probably use it as pseudocode.  I was able to run the C# project on my machine and add break points to make sure my program had the same output at each phase of the process.  The results are compatible with Google Authenticator.
[GoogleAuthCSharp](http://googleauthcsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/77706)

Here's how it works at a high level

1. Get the current unix timecode, split into 30 second increments.  Reverse the order of the bits.
2. Get/generate a unique key to this user using a PRNG.
3. Generate a SHA1-HMAC using the reversed timestamp and the user key as the inputs.
4. Grab 4 specific bits from the HMAC.  These are each individually processed using bitwise "AND"s and shifts.
5. Do a bitwise "OR" on these 4 elements together.  This generates a big integer result.
6. Do a modular division of this long integer using 1000000.  This results in the 6-digit TOTP.

See the MainWindow.xaml.cs file for the actual code.